# Missing logs and network information using DevTools and Expo 49 on Android

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, expo, devtools

When I press "j" the DevTools shows up and there is no error/warning massages. But also there are no consol.logs from my app, no request logs in network tab etc.

After app reloading I get modal inside DevTools with:

"Debugging connection was closed. Reason: WebSocket disconnected. Reconnect when ready by reopening DevTools."

And pressing reconnect doesn't work. I have to close it and reopen again with "j" and with no effect.

Sometimes, usually with first try, I can see my project files inside <MY IP>:8081, but event then its not showing logs.

The problem is Android, tried with real device and with wiped out emulators, with no effect.

On iOS after few refreshes I can see logs, but not always, like sometimes it shows, sometimes doesnt. Network requests looks fine.

I guess It should be something with ports?

Normally I'm using Flipper in most of my projects and there I can see my logs and network, but I would like to try something fresh. Im working on MacOS 13.2.1 M1

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.13",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5"
  },
```

I tried `chrome://inspect/#devices` and I can see my emulator there, but not the expo app.

I created simple Expo app as suggested in docs: `npx create-expo-app StickerSmash`

and added simple fetch code and some consol.logs, so my App.js looks like that:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native"

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("")
  console.log("App")
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect")
    const apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        console.log("Start fetching")
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
        const data = await response.json()
        const userName = data[0]?.username

        if (userName) {
          setUser(userName)
        }

        console.log("Data from the API:", data[0].username)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error)
      }
    }

    // Calling the fetchData function
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>`Fetched user: {user}`</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
})
```